# GUI Disappears when window is hidden and shown again

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

Here is what my window looks like when it is first open :

[image]

After minimizing it and opening it back again, the UI disappears and the window becomes unusable :

[image]

Where can it come from ? How should debug this behaviour?

(I am not posting my code since I don't know where the problem can be - posting hundreds of line may not be very productive - I will edit this question and post the code if I can pinpoint the problem)

Thank you

Comment: What platform and the toolkit? What version of wxWIdgets/wxPython? Can you reproduce it in a demo supplied with wxPython?

Comment: If you can create a small, runnable example that shows this behavior, that would certainly be best. By the way, if you resize the frame, do the widget reappear?